# How do I use Threads to perform a function as long as there is elements in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, arraylist

I'm trying to move my client network processing code into another thread, so it doesn't hang the main thread when processing a packet.

Basically I have an ArrayList of packets received. The Thread runs an infinite while loop, processing any new packets. However this puts my CPU up to 100%, because even if there are no new packets, it still loops continuously.

What I want to do, is have the processing thread sleeping, and my thread, notify it, when there are new packets.

I'm coding this in Java.

**EDIT:**

This is what I am striving to achieve -

```
// Main Thread
// Listener
public void newPacketReceived(){
    receiverThread.addNewPacketToProcessingQueue(null);

}

// Receiver Thread
ArrayList<GamePacket> processingQueue = new ArrayList<GamePacket>();

public void addNewPacketToProcessingQueue(GamePacket packet){
    processingQueue.add(packet);
    this.notify();
}

public void run(){
    while(true){
        // Process Packets
        this.sleep(); // Sleep until thread is notified 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using an `ArrayList`, use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) of some description (e.g. [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)). That's designed for exactly this sort of use case.

The producer code will use `offer` to offer a new element, and the processing thread will use `poll` with a timeout to block (cheaply) until an element is present.

Comment: Could you please explain how this would be used in relevance to the (new) pseudocode I have provided in the question?

Comment: @LiamE-p: Sorry, no, I haven't got time right now. But find a tutorial on it and it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: If you look at the javadoc of [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) you find a working example of a producer-consumer problem. In your case the main thread would be the producer, and the receiver thread the consumer

Answer (score 0):

You could simply [add a `Thread.sleep(100)` to your loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) while waiting for input.

It might not be the most elegant design, as the thread would still consume some sort of resources, but it will keep your processor from pegging.

If you're concerned about losing time while waiting, you could try `Thread.sleep(0)`.  Normally this isn't a good practice, but for games it is sometimes used (at least it is in other languages - haven't tried it on Java).  On some systems this will simply give up the timeslice.

Comment: Its a realtime game, so I don't want to lose any time processing potentially important data

Comment: @LiamE-p: Updated to be more specific to games.  It depends on what sort of data it is processing.  If it is video or physics data, you could try using values that work well against your screen refresh/timeslice.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code it would be difficult to help, but my suggestion is to have the one thread run with a do...while(ArrayList.size() > 0) and then running another thread running to constantly check the size of the array, should stuff be added it will start the 1st thread and stop it once it reaches zero.

Hope this helps.